# Align column next to filters

Tags: html, css

I have the following html template.

I would like to create the following layout:

[image]

Find below my current layout:

```css
// Layout
.facet-container #facet_selection {
  width: 20%;
  padding: 1%;
  margin-right: 2%;
}

.page-template-page-facet .facet-container .entry-content {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  width: 74%;
  /*width: 960px;*/
}

.page-template-page-facet .facet-container .entry-content-mobile {
  display: none;
}

.facet-container .faceted .tr>span>span:first-child {
  display: none;
}


/*! Tablet --------- */

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  /*#top-container{width:100%;margin:0;}
    #top-container .container{padding:0 .5%;}*/
  .page-template-page-facet .site-content,
  .page-template-page-facet .sidebar {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .page-template-page-facet .facet-container .entry-content,
  .facet-container .entry-content {
    width: 74%;
  }
  .page-template-page-facet .facet-container .entry-content .model .one_half {
    width: 100%;
  }
}


/* 480px iphone landscape */

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .page-template-page-facet .site-content,
  .page-template-page-facet .sidebar {
    max-width: 100% !important;
  }
  #masthead {
    display: none;
  }
  .mobile-container {
    display: block;
  }
  .page-template-page-facet .facet-container .entry-content-mobile {
    display: block;
  }
  .page-template-page-facet .facet-container .entry-content-web {
    display: none;
  }
  .facet-container #facet_selection {
    width: 100% !important;
    padding: 2% 0;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto 15px;
  }
  .facet-container #facet_selection p,
  .facet-container #facet_selection div {
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-right: 3%;
  }
  .page-template-page-facet .facet-container .entry-content,
  .facet-container .entry-content {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
  }
  .facet-container .entry-content .header_chart {
    display: none;
  }
  .facet-container .faceted .tr>span {
    width: 100% !important;
    padding: 0 0 15px;
    float: none;
  }
  .facet-container .faceted .tr>span>span:first-child {
    width: 100% !important;
    display: inline-block;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #949599;
    line-height: 26.9472px;
    margin: 0 0 15px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center !important;
    color: #fff;
  }
  .facet-container .faceted .price {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  .facet-container .faceted .button {
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
  .facet-container .faceted .making ul {
    margin-left: 22px;
  }
}

#facet_selection {
  float: left;
  width: 216px;
  display: block;
  background: #F3F3F4 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #949599;
}


/*
#facet_selection {
    width: 260px;
    padding: 1%;
    margin-right: 2%;
}
*/

#facet_selection .title {
  font-size: 17px !important;
}

#facet_selection p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}

// Format specific texts

/*
 #facet_selection [data-value|="10"], #facet_selection [data-value|="d0264e01e5513ea88f33355707702db1"], #facet_selection [data-value|="lange-haltbarkeit-und-qualitativ-hochwertige-verarbeitung."], #facet_selection [data-value|="ad162e3abe0b9286599db78d3a9d5178"], #facet_selection [data-value|="badenia"] {
     color: #0274BE;
     font-weight: bold;
     float: left;
}
*/

.entry-content2 {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.facetwp-slider-wrap {
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.facetwp-counts {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.sort_title,
.facetwp-sort {
  float: left;
}

.facetwp-sort {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.facetwp-dropdown {
  font-size: 12px !important;
}

div.facetwp-template:nth-child>div:nth-child>div:nth-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid darkgray;
}

div.facetwp-template>div>div>div>div>div>img {
  width: 150px;
}

.fwpl-layout {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry-content" itemprop="text">

  <div class="facet-container">
    <div id="facet_selection">
      <p class="title">Brand</p>
      <div class="facetwp-facet facetwp-facet-brand facetwp-type-checkboxes" data-name="brand" data-type="checkboxes">
        <div class="facetwp-checkbox" data-value="Test"><span class="facetwp-display-value">Test</span><span class="facetwp-counter">(24)</span></div>
        <div class="facetwp-checkbox" data-value="test"><span class="facetwp-display-value">Test</span><span class="facetwp-counter">(22)</span></div>
        <div class="facetwp-checkbox" data-value="aya"><span class="facetwp-display-value">Test</span><span class="facetwp-counter">(11)</span></div>
        <div class="facetwp-checkbox" data-value="ayn"><span class="facetwp-display-value">Test</span><span class="facetwp-counter">(7)</span></div>
        <div class="facetwp-overflow facetwp-hidden">
        </div><a class="facetwp-toggle">See 5 more</a><a class="facetwp-toggle facetwp-hidden">See less</a></div>
      <p class="title">OS</p>
      <div class="facetwp-facet facetwp-facet-os facetwp-type-checkboxes" data-name="os" data-type="checkboxes">
        <div class="facetwp-checkbox" data-value="Test"><span class="facetwp-display-value">Test</span><span class="facetwp-counter">(48)</span></div>
        <div class="facetwp-checkbox" data-value="linux"><span class="facetwp-display-value">Linux</span><span class="facetwp-counter">(23)</span></div>
        <div class="facetwp-checkbox" data-value="windows"><span class="facetwp-display-value">Windows</span><span class="facetwp-counter">(22)</span></div>
        <div class="facetwp-checkbox" data-value="Test"><span class="facetwp-display-value">Test</span><span class="facetwp-counter">(13)</span></div>
        <div class="facetwp-overflow facetwp-hidden">
        </div><a class="facetwp-toggle">See 5 more</a><a class="facetwp-toggle facetwp-hidden">See less</a></div>
              <p class="title">Test</p>
      <div class="facetwp-facet facetwp-facet-os facetwp-type-checkboxes" data-name="os" data-type="checkboxes">
        <div class="facetwp-checkbox" data-value="Test"><span class="facetwp-display-value">Test</span><span class="facetwp-counter">(48)</span></div>
        <div class="facetwp-checkbox" data-value="linux"><span class="facetwp-display-value">Linux</span><span class="facetwp-counter">(23)</span></div>
        <div class="facetwp-checkbox" data-value="windows"><span class="facetwp-display-value">Windows</span><span class="facetwp-counter">(22)</span></div>
        <div class="facetwp-checkbox" data-value="Test"><span class="facetwp-display-value">Test</span><span class="facetwp-counter">(13)</span></div>
        <div class="facetwp-overflow facetwp-hidden">
        </div><a class="facetwp-toggle">See 5 more</a><a class="facetwp-toggle facetwp-hidden">See less</a></div>
      <button class="sbutton"><strong>Filter zurücksetzen</strong></button>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="entry-content2">
    <div class="entry-content-web">
      <p class="p1">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book</u>.
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley</p>
    </div>

    <span class="sort_title">Elements:  </span>
    <div class="facetwp-counts">Showing 1–10 of 207 results</div> <span class="sort_title">Sorted by:</span>
    <div class="facetwp-sort">
      <select class="facetwp-sort-select">
        <option value="default">Sort by</option>
        <option value="title_asc">Title (A-Z)</option>
        <option value="title_desc">Title (Z-A)</option>
        <option value="date_desc">Date (Newest)</option>
        <option value="date_asc">Date (Oldest)</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="facetwp-template" data-name="all_consoles">
      <div class="fwpl-layout el-hkhimk">
        <div class="fwpl-result r1">
          <div class="fwpl-row el-8cjrpw">
            <div class="fwpl-col fwpl-col el-1tvcxf">
              <div class="fwpl-item el-cnyj7f"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/49/Fredmeyer_edit_1.jpg/1920px-Fredmeyer_edit_1.jpg" title="Test 1" alt="Test 1"></div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-3kkecq">Test 1</div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-s0uvqw">Brand 1</div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-73zj5">Category 1</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fwpl-result r2">
          <div class="fwpl-row el-8cjrpw">
            <div class="fwpl-col fwpl-col el-1tvcxf">
              <div class="fwpl-item el-cnyj7f is-empty"></div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-3kkecq">Test</div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-s0uvqw">Test</div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-73zj5">Test</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fwpl-result r3">
          <div class="fwpl-row el-8cjrpw">
            <div class="fwpl-col fwpl-col el-1tvcxf">
              <div class="fwpl-item el-cnyj7f is-empty"></div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-3kkecq">Test</div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-s0uvqw">Test</div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-73zj5">Test</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fwpl-result r4">
          <div class="fwpl-row el-8cjrpw">
            <div class="fwpl-col fwpl-col el-1tvcxf">
              <div class="fwpl-item el-cnyj7f is-empty"></div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-3kkecq">Test</div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-s0uvqw">Test</div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-73zj5">Test</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fwpl-result r5">
          <div class="fwpl-row el-8cjrpw">
            <div class="fwpl-col fwpl-col el-1tvcxf">
              <div class="fwpl-item el-cnyj7f is-empty"></div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-3kkecq">Test</div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-s0uvqw">Test</div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-73zj5">-</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fwpl-result r6">
          <div class="fwpl-row el-8cjrpw">
            <div class="fwpl-col fwpl-col el-1tvcxf">
              <div class="fwpl-item el-cnyj7f is-empty"></div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-3kkecq">Test</div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-s0uvqw">Test</div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-73zj5">-</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fwpl-result r7">
          <div class="fwpl-row el-8cjrpw">
            <div class="fwpl-col fwpl-col el-1tvcxf">
              <div class="fwpl-item el-cnyj7f is-empty"></div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-3kkecq">Test</div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-s0uvqw">Test</div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-73zj5">Test</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fwpl-result r8">
          <div class="fwpl-row el-8cjrpw">
            <div class="fwpl-col fwpl-col el-1tvcxf">
              <div class="fwpl-item el-cnyj7f is-empty"></div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-3kkecq">Test</div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-s0uvqw">Test</div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-73zj5">Test</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fwpl-result r9">
          <div class="fwpl-row el-8cjrpw">
            <div class="fwpl-col fwpl-col el-1tvcxf">
              <div class="fwpl-item el-cnyj7f is-empty"></div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-3kkecq">Test</div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-s0uvqw">Test</div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-73zj5">Test</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fwpl-result r10">
          <div class="fwpl-row el-8cjrpw">
            <div class="fwpl-col fwpl-col el-1tvcxf">
              <div class="fwpl-item el-cnyj7f is-empty"></div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-3kkecq">Test</div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-s0uvqw">Test</div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-73zj5">-</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <style>
        .fwpl-layout,
        .fwpl-row {
          display: grid;
        }
        
        .fwpl-layout.el-hkhimk {
          grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
          grid-gap: 10px;
        }
        
        .fwpl-layout.el-hkhimk .fwpl-result {
          border-style: solid;
          border-color: #c0c0c0;
        }
        
        .fwpl-row.el-8cjrpw {
          grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        }
        
        .fwpl-col.el-1tvcxf {
          padding: 10px;
        }
      </style>
    </div>
    <div class="facetwp-pager">
      <div class="facetwp-pager"><a class="facetwp-page first active" data-page="1">1</a><a class="facetwp-page" data-page="2">2</a><a class="facetwp-page" data-page="3">3</a><a class="facetwp-page dots">…</a><a class="facetwp-page last" data-page="21">21</a><a class="facetwp-page next"
          data-page="2">&gt;&gt;</a></div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

My problem is that I cannot put the boxes (with the images) next to the filters.

I tried using `.fwpl-layout { clear:both; }` which buts the boxes below the filters but not next to it.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding style to correct selectors.

You are trying to add style `width: 74%` to `entry-content` class which is your main wrapper of `facet-container` and `entry-content2` div elements.

Check the code on your local environment and make necessary changes. Code snippet executor is considering media queries due to small width available to run the code snippet over here.

```css
// Layout
.facet-container {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  margin-right: 2%;
}

.entry-content2 {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  width: 74%;
}

.page-template-page-facet .facet-container .entry-content-mobile {
  display: none;
}

.facet-container .faceted .tr>span>span:first-child {
  display: none;
}


/*! Tablet --------- */

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  /*#top-container{width:100%;margin:0;}
    #top-container .container{padding:0 .5%;}*/
  .page-template-page-facet .site-content,
  .page-template-page-facet .sidebar {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .page-template-page-facet .facet-container .entry-content,
  .facet-container .entry-content {
    width: 74%;
  }
  .page-template-page-facet .facet-container .entry-content .model .one_half {
    width: 100%;
  }
}


/* 480px iphone landscape */

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .page-template-page-facet .site-content,
  .page-template-page-facet .sidebar {
    max-width: 100% !important;
  }
  #masthead {
    display: none;
  }
  .mobile-container {
    display: block;
  }
  .page-template-page-facet .facet-container .entry-content-mobile {
    display: block;
  }
  .page-template-page-facet .facet-container .entry-content-web {
    display: none;
  }
  .facet-container #facet_selection {
    width: 100% !important;
    padding: 2% 0;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto 15px;
  }
  .facet-container #facet_selection p,
  .facet-container #facet_selection div {
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-right: 3%;
  }
  .page-template-page-facet .facet-container .entry-content,
  .facet-container .entry-content {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
  }
  .facet-container .entry-content .header_chart {
    display: none;
  }
  .facet-container .faceted .tr>span {
    width: 100% !important;
    padding: 0 0 15px;
    float: none;
  }
  .facet-container .faceted .tr>span>span:first-child {
    width: 100% !important;
    display: inline-block;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #949599;
    line-height: 26.9472px;
    margin: 0 0 15px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center !important;
    color: #fff;
  }
  .facet-container .faceted .price {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  .facet-container .faceted .button {
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
  .facet-container .faceted .making ul {
    margin-left: 22px;
  }
}

#facet_selection {
  float: left;
  width: 216px;
  display: block;
  background: #F3F3F4 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #949599;
}


/*
#facet_selection {
    width: 260px;
    padding: 1%;
    margin-right: 2%;
}
*/

#facet_selection .title {
  font-size: 17px !important;
}

#facet_selection p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}

// Format specific texts

/*
 #facet_selection [data-value|="10"], #facet_selection [data-value|="d0264e01e5513ea88f33355707702db1"], #facet_selection [data-value|="lange-haltbarkeit-und-qualitativ-hochwertige-verarbeitung."], #facet_selection [data-value|="ad162e3abe0b9286599db78d3a9d5178"], #facet_selection [data-value|="badenia"] {
     color: #0274BE;
     font-weight: bold;
     float: left;
}
*/

.entry-content2 {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.facetwp-slider-wrap {
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.facetwp-counts {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.sort_title,
.facetwp-sort {
  float: left;
}

.facetwp-sort {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.facetwp-dropdown {
  font-size: 12px !important;
}

div.facetwp-template:nth-child>div:nth-child>div:nth-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid darkgray;
}

div.facetwp-template>div>div>div>div>div>img {
  width: 150px;
}

.fwpl-layout {
  clear: both;
}

.fwpl-layout,
.fwpl-row {
  display: grid;
}

.fwpl-layout.el-hkhimk {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.fwpl-layout.el-hkhimk .fwpl-result {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #c0c0c0;
}

.fwpl-row.el-8cjrpw {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}

.fwpl-col.el-1tvcxf {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry-content" itemprop="text">

  <div class="facet-container">
    <div id="facet_selection">
      <p class="title">Brand</p>
      <div class="facetwp-facet facetwp-facet-brand facetwp-type-checkboxes" data-name="brand" data-type="checkboxes">
        <div class="facetwp-checkbox" data-value="Test"><span class="facetwp-display-value">Test</span><span class="facetwp-counter">(24)</span></div>
        <div class="facetwp-checkbox" data-value="test"><span class="facetwp-display-value">Test</span><span class="facetwp-counter">(22)</span></div>
        <div class="facetwp-checkbox" data-value="aya"><span class="facetwp-display-value">Test</span><span class="facetwp-counter">(11)</span></div>
        <div class="facetwp-checkbox" data-value="ayn"><span class="facetwp-display-value">Test</span><span class="facetwp-counter">(7)</span></div>
        <div class="facetwp-overflow facetwp-hidden">
        </div><a class="facetwp-toggle">See 5 more</a><a class="facetwp-toggle facetwp-hidden">See less</a></div>
      <p class="title">OS</p>
      <div class="facetwp-facet facetwp-facet-os facetwp-type-checkboxes" data-name="os" data-type="checkboxes">
        <div class="facetwp-checkbox" data-value="Test"><span class="facetwp-display-value">Test</span><span class="facetwp-counter">(48)</span></div>
        <div class="facetwp-checkbox" data-value="linux"><span class="facetwp-display-value">Linux</span><span class="facetwp-counter">(23)</span></div>
        <div class="facetwp-checkbox" data-value="windows"><span class="facetwp-display-value">Windows</span><span class="facetwp-counter">(22)</span></div>
        <div class="facetwp-checkbox" data-value="Test"><span class="facetwp-display-value">Test</span><span class="facetwp-counter">(13)</span></div>
        <div class="facetwp-overflow facetwp-hidden">
        </div><a class="facetwp-toggle">See 5 more</a><a class="facetwp-toggle facetwp-hidden">See less</a></div>
      <p class="title">Test</p>
      <div class="facetwp-facet facetwp-facet-os facetwp-type-checkboxes" data-name="os" data-type="checkboxes">
        <div class="facetwp-checkbox" data-value="Test"><span class="facetwp-display-value">Test</span><span class="facetwp-counter">(48)</span></div>
        <div class="facetwp-checkbox" data-value="linux"><span class="facetwp-display-value">Linux</span><span class="facetwp-counter">(23)</span></div>
        <div class="facetwp-checkbox" data-value="windows"><span class="facetwp-display-value">Windows</span><span class="facetwp-counter">(22)</span></div>
        <div class="facetwp-checkbox" data-value="Test"><span class="facetwp-display-value">Test</span><span class="facetwp-counter">(13)</span></div>
        <div class="facetwp-overflow facetwp-hidden">
        </div><a class="facetwp-toggle">See 5 more</a><a class="facetwp-toggle facetwp-hidden">See less</a></div>
      <button class="sbutton"><strong>Filter zurücksetzen</strong></button>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="entry-content2">
    <div class="entry-content-web">
      <p class="p1">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book</u>.
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley</p>
    </div>

    <span class="sort_title">Elements:  </span>
    <div class="facetwp-counts">Showing 1–10 of 207 results</div> <span class="sort_title">Sorted by:</span>
    <div class="facetwp-sort">
      <select class="facetwp-sort-select">
        <option value="default">Sort by</option>
        <option value="title_asc">Title (A-Z)</option>
        <option value="title_desc">Title (Z-A)</option>
        <option value="date_desc">Date (Newest)</option>
        <option value="date_asc">Date (Oldest)</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="facetwp-template" data-name="all_consoles">
      <div class="fwpl-layout el-hkhimk">
        <div class="fwpl-result r1">
          <div class="fwpl-row el-8cjrpw">
            <div class="fwpl-col fwpl-col el-1tvcxf">
              <div class="fwpl-item el-cnyj7f"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/49/Fredmeyer_edit_1.jpg/1920px-Fredmeyer_edit_1.jpg" title="Test 1" alt="Test 1"></div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-3kkecq">Test 1</div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-s0uvqw">Brand 1</div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-73zj5">Category 1</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fwpl-result r2">
          <div class="fwpl-row el-8cjrpw">
            <div class="fwpl-col fwpl-col el-1tvcxf">
              <div class="fwpl-item el-cnyj7f is-empty"></div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-3kkecq">Test</div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-s0uvqw">Test</div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-73zj5">Test</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fwpl-result r3">
          <div class="fwpl-row el-8cjrpw">
            <div class="fwpl-col fwpl-col el-1tvcxf">
              <div class="fwpl-item el-cnyj7f is-empty"></div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-3kkecq">Test</div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-s0uvqw">Test</div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-73zj5">Test</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fwpl-result r4">
          <div class="fwpl-row el-8cjrpw">
            <div class="fwpl-col fwpl-col el-1tvcxf">
              <div class="fwpl-item el-cnyj7f is-empty"></div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-3kkecq">Test</div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-s0uvqw">Test</div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-73zj5">Test</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fwpl-result r5">
          <div class="fwpl-row el-8cjrpw">
            <div class="fwpl-col fwpl-col el-1tvcxf">
              <div class="fwpl-item el-cnyj7f is-empty"></div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-3kkecq">Test</div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-s0uvqw">Test</div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-73zj5">-</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fwpl-result r6">
          <div class="fwpl-row el-8cjrpw">
            <div class="fwpl-col fwpl-col el-1tvcxf">
              <div class="fwpl-item el-cnyj7f is-empty"></div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-3kkecq">Test</div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-s0uvqw">Test</div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-73zj5">-</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fwpl-result r7">
          <div class="fwpl-row el-8cjrpw">
            <div class="fwpl-col fwpl-col el-1tvcxf">
              <div class="fwpl-item el-cnyj7f is-empty"></div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-3kkecq">Test</div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-s0uvqw">Test</div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-73zj5">Test</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fwpl-result r8">
          <div class="fwpl-row el-8cjrpw">
            <div class="fwpl-col fwpl-col el-1tvcxf">
              <div class="fwpl-item el-cnyj7f is-empty"></div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-3kkecq">Test</div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-s0uvqw">Test</div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-73zj5">Test</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fwpl-result r9">
          <div class="fwpl-row el-8cjrpw">
            <div class="fwpl-col fwpl-col el-1tvcxf">
              <div class="fwpl-item el-cnyj7f is-empty"></div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-3kkecq">Test</div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-s0uvqw">Test</div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-73zj5">Test</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fwpl-result r10">
          <div class="fwpl-row el-8cjrpw">
            <div class="fwpl-col fwpl-col el-1tvcxf">
              <div class="fwpl-item el-cnyj7f is-empty"></div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-3kkecq">Test</div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-s0uvqw">Test</div>
              <div class="fwpl-item el-73zj5">-</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <style>
        .fwpl-layout,
        .fwpl-row {
          display: grid;
        }
        
        .fwpl-layout.el-hkhimk {
          grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
          grid-gap: 10px;
        }
        
        .fwpl-layout.el-hkhimk .fwpl-result {
          border-style: solid;
          border-color: #c0c0c0;
        }
        
        .fwpl-row.el-8cjrpw {
          grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        }
        
        .fwpl-col.el-1tvcxf {
          padding: 10px;
        }
      </style>
    </div>
    <div class="facetwp-pager">
      <div class="facetwp-pager"><a class="facetwp-page first active" data-page="1">1</a><a class="facetwp-page" data-page="2">2</a><a class="facetwp-page" data-page="3">3</a><a class="facetwp-page dots">…</a><a class="facetwp-page last" data-page="21">21</a><a class="facetwp-page next"
          data-page="2">&gt;&gt;</a></div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

This is how it looks on my local environment.

[image: implementation on my local environment]